# October CMS-How pass variable to a component in a {% for ... endfor %} loop?

Tags: for-loop, twig, octobercms

I can't understand this. In this example `trucs` is an non empty array. When I wrote :

```
{% for truc in trucs %}

   {{ truc.foo }}

   {% component 'myComponent' truc=truc %}

{% enfor %}
```

I can read `{{ truc.foo }}` but array `truc` is empty in my component `myComponent` whereas `trucs` is available. Could it be linked with the [Page execution life cycle handlers](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#page-cycle-handlers) ? In that case, when and/or where could I inject `truc` ?

Comment: your value will be available in `onRender`, so you can access it like  `$this->property('truc')` but it will NOT available in `onRun` method as per life cycle.

Comment: Ok ! It works with : ```$this->page['truc'] = $this->property('truc')``` in the component... Many thanks !